# How i cane can do angular cross domain post request?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, yii2

I have frontend made by angular. And backend made by yii2 (rest).
I added 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*' header in backend.
How i cane can do angular cross domain post request?
If i execute this code, i had OPTIONS request, not POST:

```
$http
        .post(API_URL+'auth/login', $scope.credentials)
        .error(function(error){
            Notification.error(error.message);
            $scope.credentials.sending = false;
        })
        .then(function (res) {
            $cookies.putObject('currentUser', res.data);
            $rootScope.user = res.data;
            $state.go('dashboard');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some features using cors. If you use cookie you should use with-credentials flag and allow this header in backend. Also there're some headers. You can read about it here. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: I don't use cookies. And i need setting exactly angular

Comment: So u need define allow headers on back-end side. it works for me as well. Example:  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS, PUT')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin')